# Setting up a subdomain to a distinct server

Tags: domain-name-system, internet

I am setting up a subdomain on Google Domains in the form *subdomain.mydomain.com*, so that this URL lead users to my server (AWS EC2 instance). In [Google Domains](https://domains.google/) I can configure subdoamins with Registered hosts or Synthetic records. But when I do that and specify my server's IP address (or an external URL) it just redirects a browser to that IP address (or the external URL) and user sees it in the browser's address bar instead of *subdomain.mydomain.com*.

How can I configure the subdomain in [Google Domains](https://domains.google/), such that the traffic gets routed to a distinct server and server's IP is not visible (not a part of the external communication at all)?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to set the subdomain up as a resource record: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290350

Registered Hosts ("glue records") are mainly for name servers. Synthetic Records are mainly for third-party integrations.

After making the changes, you may also have an issue where the site your subdomain is pointing it is redirecting to the IP address. You can use a tool like curl to verify: `curl -I -X GET http://subdomain.domain/`

If curl's output says something like 301 or 302 then the site itself is also redirecting and you'll need to look into why that is. The browser may also be caching any of the redirects so you may need to clear your cache and restart the browser.

Comment: thanks for answer. I added Custom resource record with type A and set IP-address, the curl -I -X GET http://subdomain.mydomain.com returns 404, whilst curl -I -X GET http://IP returns 200

Comment: @VicK it usually takes time for records to propagate, and since you're probably using the same subdomain, it's likely cached by a DNS resolver, such as your ISP's. since it sounds like it was setup as a registered host at first, it could be cached for over a day. try using a different subdomain to test.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rob-olmos for pointing to the resource record that was a right track. Sharing the full solution, which may be helpful to others.

I ended up creating a hosted zone and 2 record sets in AWS Route 53: 1) a record set of type `NS` and 2) one of type `A`. 1) The former generates 4 Name Servers for `subdomain.mydomain.com`, following samples:

```
ns-2048.awsdns-64.com  
ns-2049.awsdns-65.net  
ns-2050.awsdns-66.org  
ns-2051.awsdns-67.co.uk
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html) some more details on Rout 53 NS.
2) The latter record set maps the `subdomain.mydomain.com` with the actual IP of the EC2 instance.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html) doc describes how to route the traffic to EC2, but it covers only the second record set (adding the type A mapping) and misses the NS records.

The next step is adding resource record with type **NS** (type A didn't work for me as it exposes ip-address) for *subdomain* in your registrar (in my case google domains). The **NS** type of resource record is critical in routing traffic without exposing server's IP-address. So, in Google Domains I went to `Custom resource records` and added those 4 ns name servers, generated in Route 53.

And that's it, works like a charm.